# Windows configuration automation

Tags: windows-10, automation

I am preparing computers for new employees in our company. Over the time it became very repetitive task, so I am thinking if I can automate the process by writing some script.

I need the script to:

1. Create new windows local user (with specified username & password)
2. For the new user show "This PC" icon on the desktop, put some applications shortcut to the desktop and remove others (Edge, Windows Store etc.).
3. Add e-mail account to Outlook and connect it to our IMAP & SMTP servers.

I'm sure in 2019 there will be some technology which can be easily used for this kind of automation. Probably developed right from Microsoft (maybe PowerShell?).

Which technology/language/framework should I take a look for automate these tasks? We have mostly Windows 10 Home in the company.

Comment: [How to create an unattended installation of Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-unattended-media-do-automated-installation-windows-10)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to install new Windows. The Windows is already installed on the laptops. And the username, password and e-mail account will differ every user.

Comment: Have you considered configuring [MDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/mdt/) ([download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54259))?  Depending on how many PCs you have to configure and how often, it may be worth the time to set up MDT... it has ~1hr learning curve and is quite simple to use.  It also has a GUI for the answer file [`unattend.xml`] setup.

Comment: It looks like I need to have Active Directory server? I don't have ;-)

Comment: Isn't there just simple way to use some kind of script? Just enter USB stick, run the script with admin privilege and done. (In Linux it would not be a problem, I'm sure)